# Propositions and proof: Relation between convex sets and convex combinations

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

I have had some troubles when trying to rephrase and prove the things I am reading on different books. I would like to prove the equivalence of defining a convex set the usual way, or as a set which contains all convex combinations of its points.

**Definition of Convex Combination**
A point of the form $\alpha_1x_1 + \alpha_2 x_2 + \cdots + \alpha_k x_k$ where $\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + \cdots + \alpha_k = 1$ and $\alpha_i \geq 0, \; i = 1, 2, \ldots, k$ is called a convex combination of the points $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k$

**Proposition 1**
Let $V$ be a vector space, and $\vec{x}_i \in V$, $i=1,\ldots,k$. Let $C$ be the set of all convex combinations of $\vec{x}_i$, then $C$ is convex

**Proposition 2**
Let $V$ be a vector space, and $\vec{x}_i \in V$, $i=1,\ldots,k$. Let $C$ be a convex set containing all $\vec{x}_i$ then all convex combinations of $\vec{x}_i$ are contained in $C$

From these propositions, can we say this ?

**Proposition 3**
Let $V$ be a vector space, and $\vec{x}_i \in V$, $i=1,\ldots,k$. Let $C$ be a set containing all $\vec{x}_i$ then $C$ is convex if and only if it contains every convex combinations of $\vec{x}_i$

I have been able to prove (2) by induction and could do the same for (1). But would such a proof be valid for something like (4) ?

**Proposition 4**
Let $V$ be a vector space. A set $C \subset V$ is convex if and only if it contains every convex combinations of its points.

And is (3) equivalent (4) ? If not, how can I prove (4) as it is stated, or rephrase it to be able to ?

Answer (score 1):

4) can be proved exactly like 2), using induction. 3) is false. Only one way implication is true. If $C$ contains all convex combinations of the given points it need not be convex. There may be other points in $C$ some of whose convex combinations do not belong to $C$.

Comment: Yes, Kavi, just making a set which is formed by the convex combinations of $x_i$, and making the union with a singleton whose element is $-1x_1$, for example, will make (3) false. I actually misread "Let C be the set of all convex combinations " from (1) to "Let C contain every convex combinations " in (3). Thanks for pointing that out. But in (4) when I say "if it contains every convex combinations of its points.", then it is right, right ? Also, can I use induction to prove (4) even though the number of elements in the set is uncountable ?

Comment: @bpbutti the set may be uncountable but you only have to prove that finite convex combinations of its points belong to it. So you can use induction for 4) just the way you did for 2).